# Git bash (Windows 10): how to call python scripts starting the input line without "python -m"

Tags: python, git-bash, aliases

I am using git bash on Windows 10.
In order to run script like pip, virtualenv, gunicorn, etc. installed in

> C:\installation_path_of_python_3.7\scripts

I have to type

```
python -m selected_script
```

Is there a way to call the scripts simply by typing

```
selected_script
```

?

I found out that by opening the file aliases.sh in

> C:\installation_path_of_git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh

and adding lines like

```
alias pip='C:/installation_path_of_python_3.7/Phyton/Scripts/virtualenv.exe'
```

I can one by one enable git to call scripts, i.e.

> virtualenv ...

Is there a way to automatically create an alias for every other script that I will install in that folder?

Comment: Add to `path` var

Comment: If you are typing script names from bash, you need to add line ```#!/usr/bin/env python3``` as the first line to your scripts.